# How can you work out why FIles.isWritable() returns false on Windows

Tags: java, windows, file, security

In my application that allows users to modify their music files occasionally I have a problem when application does not have permissions to modify a file but the user is convinced they have given it full permissions

I've discovered the Java 7 improvements and wrote this method to output the permissions

```
public static String displayPermissions(Path path)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("File "+path + " permissions\n");
    try
    {
        {
            AclFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, AclFileAttributeView.class);
            if (view != null)
            {
                for (AclEntry acl : view.getAcl())
                {
                    sb.append(acl+"\n");
                }
            }
        }

        {
            PosixFileAttributeView view = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, PosixFileAttributeView.class);
            if (view != null)
            {
                PosixFileAttributes pfa = view.readAttributes();
                sb.append(":owner:"+pfa.owner().getName()+":group:"+pfa.group().getName()+":"+PosixFilePermissions.toString(pfa.permissions())+"\n");
            }
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ioe)
    {
        logger.severe("Unable to read permissions for:"+path.toString());
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

but for Windows systems it can still be rather difficult/impossible to work out why they don't have permissions

```
WARNING: File testdata\test157.dsf permissions
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:READ_DATA/WRITE_DATA/APPEND_DATA/READ_NAMED_ATTRS/WRITE_NAMED_ATTRS/EXECUTE/DELETE_CHILD/READ_ATTRIBUTES/WRITE_ATTRIBUTES/DELETE/READ_ACL/WRITE_ACL/WRITE_OWNER/SYNCHRONIZE:DENY
BUILTIN\Administrators:READ_DATA/WRITE_DATA/APPEND_DATA/READ_NAMED_ATTRS/WRITE_NAMED_ATTRS/EXECUTE/DELETE_CHILD/READ_ATTRIBUTES/WRITE_ATTRIBUTES/DELETE/READ_ACL/WRITE_ACL/WRITE_OWNER/SYNCHRONIZE:DENY
BUILTIN\Administrators:READ_DATA/WRITE_DATA/APPEND_DATA/READ_NAMED_ATTRS/WRITE_NAMED_ATTRS/EXECUTE/DELETE_CHILD/READ_ATTRIBUTES/WRITE_ATTRIBUTES/DELETE/READ_ACL/WRITE_ACL/WRITE_OWNER/SYNCHRONIZE:ALLOW
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:READ_DATA/WRITE_DATA/APPEND_DATA/READ_NAMED_ATTRS/WRITE_NAMED_ATTRS/EXECUTE/DELETE_CHILD/READ_ATTRIBUTES/WRITE_ATTRIBUTES/DELETE/READ_ACL/WRITE_ACL/WRITE_OWNER/SYNCHRONIZE:ALLOW
BUILTIN\Users:READ_DATA/READ_NAMED_ATTRS/EXECUTE/READ_ATTRIBUTES/READ_ACL/SYNCHRONIZE:ALLOW
NT AUTHORITY\Authenticated Users:READ_DATA/WRITE_DATA/APPEND_DATA/READ_NAMED_ATTRS/WRITE_NAMED_ATTRS/EXECUTE/READ_ATTRIBUTES/WRITE_ATTRIBUTES/DELETE/READ_ACL/SYNCHRONIZE:ALLOW
```

, any suggestions on how I can programmatically work out the reason for isWritable() (or isReadable()) failing.

Comment: What looks a bit strange is. `BUILTIN\Administrators` have `DENY` and `ALLOW` for the same permissions.

Comment: Well this is just an example, but I manually set permissions to Deny but couldn't seem to remove existing Allow permissions, frankjly I find Windows permissions unintelligible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the confusion comes from the fact that the effective permission depends on the directory permissions and the file permissions.

If the user has e.g. the `Write` permission for a file but not the `Modify` permission for the containing directory he has effectively not write permission to that file. See the full matix of [File and folder permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349321%28v=ws.10%29.aspx).

To do the check in Java you can use the [FileSystemProvider.checkAccess](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/spi/FileSystemProvider.html#checkAccess-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.AccessMode...-) method to check the permission of

Assume following files and permissions (all permissions out of scope are removed to make it more clear). The permissions were retrieved with the `icacls` tool.

```
c:\ BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)(RX) - read + execute permission

c:\bar BUILTIN\Users:(RX) - read + execute permission

c:\foo BUILTIN\Users:(F) - full permission
```

Sample snippet for demonstration.

```
public class AccessCheckDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String[] files = {"c:/foo", "c:/bar"};
        for (String file : files) {
            Path path = Paths.get(file);
            System.out.println("check " + path);
            System.out.println("file      Files.isWritable: "
                    + Files.isWritable(path));
            System.out.println("directory Files.isWritable: "
                    + Files.isWritable(path.getParent()));
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

output

```
check c:\foo
file      Files.isWritable: true
directory Files.isWritable: false

check c:\bar
file      Files.isWritable: true
directory Files.isWritable: false
```

Even `BUILTIN\Users` have `full permissions` on file `c:\foo` they cannot write to this file, as the permission of the directory `c:\` does not permit it (only read + execute permission for this group on `c:\`).

As already mentioned by badsamaritan ([JDK-7190897](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7190897)) this doesn't work properly in Java 7.

Comment: This is interesting, I wasn't using this method but I am already using Files.isReadable(), Files.isWritable() which seem to use it anyway. But from your example above it seems you are saying it can return true for isWritable() for a file, even though the file might not be writable because you dont have sufficient permissions in containing folder. What I want is it to return false if you don't actually have permissions to modify it, but doesnt write permissions for folder just mean you need it to create new files within folder rather than edit files in folder ? BTW Im already using Java 8.

Comment: @PaulTaylor You're right `Files.isReadable()` and `Files.isWritable()` are wrapper around the `FileSystemProvider.checkAccess()` method. If a filesystem is using ACLs then you need to read them top-down. The first matching entry is used. If the user has no permission to write to a file in a specific directory, then the permission on a contained file is not checked. This differ for example from the default Linux user/group/other schema. If the user has no write permission for a directory this means he cannot create/delete files. But he is still able to modify files if the permission allow it.

Answer (score 1):

> any suggestions on how I can programmatically work out the reason for isWritable() (or isReadable()) failing

Maybe it is real bug, not your fault:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8034863

or

http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=7190897

---

When talking about Windows permissions it is worth mentioning that they are indeed a bit strange (even Microsoft admits it): DENY has stronger priority than ALLOW, so if you allow some users to read particular file and also deny everyone every permission this deny 'overrides' everything and no one (including owner) can't read this file. That's why you don't see DENY permission selected in ACLs very often.

Comment: Thankyou that is very useful point about DENY and the second bug is very interesting as I havent updated to the bug fix version of java 8 and that may well fix some issues. But my question wasnt really 'why dont i have permission' but 'given set of Windows permissions how do I decode them to provide the effective permissions for a user'