# How can i get existing parent path from provided file path

Tags: java, file

Is there any way to get valid/existing parent from provided path without looping.

My requirement is to create folder at provided path and i want to add validation that that folder have write permission.

So I added below code. but issue is some time path of getParent is not exists

```
Files.isWritable(Paths.get(path).getParent())
```

Example

```
"C:\MyFolder\Test" is existing folder.

Case1:
path=C:\MyFolder\Test\a 
Paths.get(path).getParent() will be C:\MyFolder\Test 
Files.isWritable will be true/false based on permission of "C:\MyFolder\Test".

Case2:
path=C:\MyFolder\Test\a\b\c 
Paths.get(path).getParent() will be C:\MyFolder\Test\a\b 
Files.isWritable will be always false.
```

I can add loop like getParent() till exists and then verify Files.isWritable().
Is there any better solution to get valid/existing path.

Comment: can you add a ternary if?

Comment: Yes, i created recursive function with ternary if.

Comment: extra information from [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#isWritable(java.nio.file.Path))

**Note that result of this method is immediately outdated, there is no guarantee that a subsequent attempt to open the file for writing will succeed (or even that it will access the same file). Care should be taken when using this method in security sensitive applications.**

Comment: also, please check [How can you work out why FIles.isWritable() returns false on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082228/how-can-you-work-out-why-files-iswritable-returns-false-on-windows)

Comment: Okay, Is there any other way to add validation like does i have folder creation permission or not? or can i add such validation on exception class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [createDirectories](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) if you also want the parent directories to be created. Certainly, you'd have to extract parent directory path as you are doing it already if it's a file.

you can also optionally refer this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3024044/11065438), for the old-school way without `java.nio` package.

*Do use a **try-catch** to handle in case the directory creation fails.*