# Unexpected behavior for Files.isWritable

Tags: java, nio

`Files.isWritable` on Windows machine is always giving false in case of a file located on network (both when accessing directly or through mapped drive).

However:

1. File has write permission.
2. `FileUtils.writeStringToFile` successfully writes to this file without giving any error. (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile-java.io.File-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)

Is there a better API which can give more reliable results / permissions for file over network?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35082228/how-can-you-work-out-why-files-iswritable-returns-false-on-windows which may help. You should also add the exact permissions that your file has to your question, and tell us the user your program is running as.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you upgrade JDK if you are able to. There have been several bugs reported with `Files.isWritable` - such as [this](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8130830) and the related bugs, one of which may be the cause of your issue.

I noted similar problems when using JDK11 and added this temporary workaround for my particular case. I removed the workaround once I upgraded to JDK14/15:

```
public static boolean isWritable(Path path)
{
    boolean writable = Files.isWritable(path);
    if (!writable)
    {
        writable = path.toFile().canWrite();
    }
    return writable;
}
```